# Not receiving customized email notifications thrugh Jenkins(email extension plugin)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I configured [email ext plugin in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQh6t.png) but [received this html content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSzsh.png) in email body. [I need this type of email body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qulJE.png). Can someone has solution?

Even I tried this format also '${SCRIPT, template="groovy-text.template"}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have shared screenshots of my configuration, expected mail template body and received content. Please have a look at the images.